# Reducing data type size causes index to exceed maximum size?

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, ssms, sql-server-2016

Today I am facing a weird message. I am not sure if it is just a bug:

[image]

The tables are created by ASP.NET Identity. However, they are using `nvarchar(450)` for the Id, which, I cannot use in other tables because the index exceeds 900 bytes. Therefore I am trying to reduce it, but how could the `PK_AspNetUserRoles` be created in the first place? Is it just a SSMS bug?

Answer (score 0):

What is your SSMS version? 
IMHO, t's a bug, I cannot reproduce this issue in 12.0.4100.1.

You cannot change column type without recreating the index, so the error that you could receive might be:

Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The index 'PK_AspNetUserRoles' is dependent on column 'UserId'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 4
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN UserId failed because one or more objects access this column.

But my SSMS just silently did the following:

- create new table with the same name and tmp prefix having
  nvarchar(150)-column
- insert into new table select * from original table
- drop original table
- rename new table as old table
- create index PK on it

No error was shown

Comment: My version is `13.0.16106.4`. In that dialog, I tried clicking Yes anyway, and SSMS automatically changed all the foreign keys' data type to the new one (`nvarchar(450)` to `nvarchar(150)`)

Comment: Foreign keys? Your post said nothing about them, the error shown is about Primary key

Comment: Sorry. I changed the `Id` column of `AspNetUsers` table. And `UserId` of `AspNetUserRoles` refers to `Id`, and it is also part of the Primary Key.

Comment: Can you update your question with the definition of AspNetUserRoles PK please?